# How to Change BottomNavigationBar attributes?

Tags: android, layout

how to disable magnify and modify font_size of selected tab in ***BottomNavigationBar*** Android, I just wanna change the tab's color, don't magnify the tab, what should i do, thanks!

is there any attribute to change some attribute in this widget?

```
<com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar
    android:id="@+id/mainTabBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false"
    app:bnbActiveColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:bnbBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:bnbInactiveColor="@color/gray"
    app:bnbMode="mode_fixed"
    tools:override="true"/>
```

Comment: what have you tried? share your code

Answer (score 0):

That BottomNavigationBar is a custom component and probably has its own method of styling or inheriting a style. Can you please share how it works or references to the documentation of the component? Thank you!